# Logging Verbosity in Keepalived.conf?

Tags: linux, networking, keepalived

My keepalived VIP on one of my routers stopped responding. I still saw it on the primary router and not the secondary router as I would expect, and I could ping the regular IPs. As soon as I restarted keepalived the problem was resolved.

I am not really sure what is causing this issue, are there any log level directives I could add to my keepalived that might give me some information if this happens again?

---

I do see:

> keepalived -f /usr/local/etc/keepalived.conf --dont-fork --log-console
>   --log-detail These options will stop keepalived from fork'ing, and
>   will provide additional logging data. Using these options is
>   especially useful when you are testing out new configuration
>   directives, or debugging an issue with an existing configuration file.

So maybe I just need to edit my init file? Seems like it should be a config file option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to edit the init script.  From keepalived.conf(5) via git: http://master.formilux.org/git/people/alex/keepalived.git/

```
       # Debug level, not implemented yet.
       debug
```

You can also verify this by looking at the configuration parsing code in keepalived/check/check_parser.c:

```
265 vector
266 check_init_keywords(void)
267 {
268         /* global definitions mapping */
269         global_init_keywords();
270 
271         /* SSL mapping */
272         install_keyword_root("SSL", &ssl_handler);
273         install_keyword("password", &sslpass_handler);
```

Lists all the configuration file keywords that it parses, and debug isn't in here.  The debug levels appear to be set only via the keepalived/core/main.c options processing:

```
154                 "  %s --log-console        -l    Log message to local console.\n"
155                 "  %s --log-detail         -D    Detailed log messages.\n"
...
177                 {"log-console", 'l', POPT_ARG_NONE, NULL, 'l'},
178                 {"log-detail", 'D', POPT_ARG_NONE, NULL, 'D'},
...
209         case 'l':
210                 debug |= 1;
211                 break;
...
224         case 'D':
225                 debug |= 32;
226                 break;
```